# How to extract .mpk file package in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-license-manager, map-package, error-000824

I am trying to extract **.mpk** map package but shows me

> ERROR 000824:the tool is not licensed

[Here is the link of map which  I am trying to extract.](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=c34db98c3ca2412eb31775d7be0d06af)

Answer (score 1):

To unpack a map package, you should be able to just right click the .mpk in ArcCatalog and click "Unpack".

You shouldn't need an ArcInfo (Advanced license), using the right click method in ArcCatalog or the Extract Package tool is available for ArcView (basic), ArcEditor (standard), and ArcInfo (advanced) licenses.
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Extract_Package/0017000000vq000000/

Comment: You can also drag and drop it from the Catalog window onto the map canvas.  However,I think the user knows at least one way to try and open a map package but this map package must contain something that needs another license like an extension before it can open.